# how to display value in listbox from dataview

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

i have a textbox and listbox in a winform app. when i type a value(i.e,string) in the textbox i want the listbox to show the values from datatable and when i am selecting a particular value from listbox it will display in textbox .

code:

```
private void txtIName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            string constring = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;User Id=sa;Password=admin@123";
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT distinct * FROM Item_Details", con))
                {
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
                    {
                        using (dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);                            
                            DataView dv = new DataView(dt);
                            dv.RowFilter = string.Format("IName Like '%{0}%'", txtIName.Text);
                            listBox1.Visible = true;
                            listBox1.DataSource = dv;

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

but i got the output in listbox like "system.data.datarow". By debugging i can seen that rows which i want, in dataview 'dv'. what i am missing here? thanks.

Comment: You must set `listBox1.DisplayMember` to the column name you want to see

Comment: ya just before seen your comment i got the ouput by googling. but i dont know how to display a value in textbox from listbox. thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to load data each time the `TextChanged` event fires. It's enough to load data in `Load` event of your form and then in `TextChanged` just filter the data. Then using an event like `DoubleClick` of `ListBox` set the text of `TextBox`:

```
private DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string constring = @"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;User Id=sa;Password=admin@123";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT distinct * FROM Item_Details", con))
        {
            sda.Fill(dataTable);
        }
    }
    this.listBox1.DataSource = new DataView(dataTable);
    this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "IName";
    this.listBox1.Visible = false;
}
private void txtIName_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var dv = (DataView)this.listBox1.DataSource;
    dv.RowFilter = string.Format("IName Like '%{0}%'", txtIName.Text);
    listBox1.Visible = true;
}
private void listBox1_DoubleClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var item = (DataRowView)listBox1.SelectedItem;
    if (item != null)
        this.txtIName.Text = item["IName"].ToString();
    else
        this.txtIName.Text = "";

    this.listBox1.Visible = false;
}
```

Don't forget to attach `Form1_Load`, `txtIName_TextChanged` and `listBox1_DoubleClick` handlers to events.

Comment: please help me with coding because i am new to c#. no i dont want user to click a button to enter the data. i just want user to click enter button or mouse click to select that value.

Comment: your code shows the error as "Error 1 The type or namespace name 'DataRowview' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
"

Comment: To change the previous version code, use `DataRowView`, but I think the new code I wrote for you is a better fit.

Comment: I tested the update with corrected typos and it works properly here.

Comment: @Raja aar you missed perhaps a using of some namespace.

Comment: @Reza Aghaei Can you give him all your code. It seems to me that it is correct what you do

Comment: sorry bro i told previous code you commented and this code has a problem, listbox is shown even the first time form load. i set in design itself as visible=false.

Comment: @Rajaaar If you set `this.listBox1.Visible = false;` in `Load` event of form, it will not display, the ListBox will display after text changed. Also you can check `if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.txtIName.Text))` then make the listbox invisible.

Comment: @Rajaaar I tested the solution here and it worked properly, Let me know if you have any problem with the codes :)

Comment: working fine .thanks a lot bro.. take some time to clear all the errors because i am copy paste your code. thanks again.

Comment: @Rajaaar No problem, you can contact me using r.aghaei at outlook.com. I think it's better to post your questions here in stack overflow and if you like, inform me about your question using email and then I'll be happy if I can help you. Posting questions here increases chance of receiving more good answers. English is not the first language for most people here and we should help each other even using with weak grammar and spelling and while we enhance our programming skills we should enhance our skill in English language as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must specify your DisplayMember, it must be some Field in your DataView

```
listBox1.DisplayMember = "Your Field"
```

then you can suscribe to the event SelectedValueChanged :

```
 listBox1.SelectedValueChanged += new EventHandler(listBox1_SelectedValueChanged);
```

visual studio create for you an event handler

```
  void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // you get your selected item here
        }
```

hope it helps

Comment: yes its working. also i want to show one of the listbox value in textbox when i select from it. i am new to c#, i dont know how to display the value in it.thanks.

Comment: private void listBox1_SelectedValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            txtIName.Text = listBox1.SelectedValue.ToString();
        }   i tried this code but got the output like"system.data.datarow" .

Comment: DataRow dr = (DataRow)listBox1.SelectedItem; txtIName.Text = drv["MyField "].ToString();//replace MyField with your Field / column name [Perhaps DataRowView instead DataRow , any way the two]

Comment: shows the (red underline in the word Row) error in drv.Row

Comment: I pick this code from @Reza Agaei answer, I think this must work

Comment: @ Atmane EL BOUACHRI  thanks for your efforts bro.. yes @Reza Agaei code works fine.